Why does the cylinder/barrel on an injection moulding machine have such thick walls?
When you look at the cylinder on injection moulders, for instance on DIY ones on YouTube, they are all thick walled. The piston has say a 20mm diameter and the cylinder has like a 40mm diameter in which plastic is heated to 250C. Could you get away with using a 1" stainless steel pipe with 3mm thick walls?

Because injection molding pressures can get very high - typically peaks of 16 ksi , and the hoop stress in the steel is governed by the ratio of bore diameter to wall thickness.
Your suggested dimensions would burst at an injection pressure of around 25ksi if made from very good steel (100 ksi), and less than half that for typical stainless steels.
However real cylinders don't just break because of hoop stress, there are also stress raisers at the endplate, and there are other possible failure modes, not just hoop stress.

Also consider that such a mass will provide better thermal management.

8000 ton per square inch? Do you mean 8 tons per square inch

I didn't consider pressure because I figured the fact there's a nozzle and an escape into the mold meant that much pressure would build up, but now come to think of it, when you open a tap at the bottom of the tank with the atmosphere weighing down, the pressure in the tank is still essentially the same apart from around the tap hole.. I think. So perhaps the plastic in the barrel would reach the pressure it would if the barrel were completely sealed

Sorry yes, 16000 psi. I've redone the whole thing.

@LewisKelsey you didn't consider pressure because you think of water, however consider the viscosity of plastic at the temperatures required...
